# kohana 3 - image class and error "Cannot instantiate abstract class Image"

Tags: image, kohana

i made model which sends through controller to template neccessary data from database and doing picture resize for each picture path in the database.
don't know why but there is some error (subj).
here is code of this class method of model http://fpaste.org/ct2I/

Comment: oh used factory method and all is work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is you can't initialize abstract classes.

Using the `factory` method is required.